# Do NestJS providers need to be stateless?

Tags: spring, nestjs

I'm a long-time Spring developer learning NestJS.  The similarities are so striking, and I've loved how productive that's allowed me to be.  Some documentation has me confused about one thing however.

I try to liken Nest "providers" to Spring beans with default scope.  For example I create @Injectable service classes and think of them as analogous to Spring @Services.  As such I've assumed these service classes needed to be thread safe - no state, etc.  However, [the Nest documentation here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes) is a little ambiguous to me and kind of implies this might not be necessary (emphasis mine):

> For people coming from different programming language backgrounds, it might be unexpected to learn that in Nest, almost everything is shared across incoming requests. We have a connection pool to the database, singleton services with global state, etc. **Remember that Node.js doesn't follow the request/response Multi-Threaded Stateless Model in which every request is processed by a separate thread. Hence, using singleton instances is fully safe for our applications.**

If individual requests aren't handled in their own threads, is it OK for Nest providers to contain mutable state?  It would be up to the app to ensure each incoming request started with a "clean slate" - e.g. initializing that state with a NestInterceptor, for example.  But to me, that doc reads that providers are created as singletons, and thus can be used as something akin to a wrapper container for data, like a ThreadLocal in Java.

Am I reading this wrong, or is this a difference in behavior between Nest and Spring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should make request handling stateless.

I don't know anything about Spring, but in NestJS (and async javascript in general) it's single threaded, but doesn't block for I/O. That means the same thread of the same instance of a service can process multiple requests at once. It can only do one thing at a time, but it can start doing the next thing while the previous thing is waiting on a database query, or for the request to finish being transmitted, or for an external service to respond, or for the filesystem to deliver the contents of a file, etc.

So in one thread, with one instance of a service, this can happen:

- Request A comes in.
- Database query is dispatched for request A.
- Request B comes in.
- Database query is dispatched for request B.
- Database query for request A returns, and the response is sent.
- Database query for request B returns, and the response is sent.

What that means for state is that it will be shared between requests. If your service sets an instance property at one step of an async operation, then another async operation may start before the first was complete and set a new value for that instance property, which is probably not what you want.

I believe the "global state" the Nest docs mention is not per request, but general configuration state. Like the URL of an external service, or credentials to your database.

---

It's also worth mentioning that controllers receive a request object, which represents that specific request. It's common to add properties to that request object, like [the current authenticated user](https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#login-route) for example. The request object can be passed around to give your controller and services context in a way that is friendly to this architecture.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I was wondering if blocking IO could cause a new request to be handled.  Spring has a lot of parallels to Nest but it executes each request in a separate thead, hencee an explicit need for thread safety in e.g. services with are singletons (in the default scope).  Same net result of course.

Comment: I'm currently passing the request down to the Service tier but have an aversion to that due to strong separation-of-concerns opinions - only the Controller tier should know about HTTP & requests, Service tier should only know business logic, etc.  Hence looking for a way to store state a la Java ThreadLocals.

Comment: I would avoid passing the request object to your services, for the most part for the reasons you stated (also ease of testing). But you can pass properties of that request from the controller to your services. Like the current user for example for when a service makes a change in the DB that needs to be attributed to a user, for example.